# How can I include XML docomentation in my NuGet package in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-core

I have a *.Net Core* library targeting multiple platforms (*.Net 3.5* and *Net Standard 1.0*) therefore upon build, I get two folders one for each platform: *net35* and *netstandard1.0*.

Each of these folders have their own *MyLibrary.dll*, *MyLibrary.pdb* and *MyLibrary.xml* files.

When I run `dotnet pack`, I would like to put each of the *xml* files under the correct folder inside the *NuGet* package which I cannot figure out how to do, so at the moment given the *project.json* below, I have had to explicitly include the the *xml* file generated for the *net35* under the ***files*** configuration.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "authors": [ "John Smith" ],
  "title": "Something Awesome",
  "name": "Soemthing.Awesome",
  "description": "Something that does awesome things.",
  "copyright": "2016 John Smith",
  "packOptions": {
    "copyright": "2016 John Smith",
    "owners": [ "John Smith" ],
    "licenseUrl": "https://github.com/JohnSmith/LICENSE",
    "projectUrl": "https://github.com/JohnSmith/SomethingAwesome",
    "requireLicenseAcceptance": false,
    "summary": "Brings awesomeness to your project.",
    "tags": [ "Awesome" ],
    "releaseNotes": ""https://github.com/JohnSmith/SomethingAwesome/1.0",
    "files": "bin\\Release\\net35\\Something.Awesome.xml",    
    "repository": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com/JohnSmith/SomethingAwesome"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net35": {},
    "netstandard1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50",
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1"
      },
      "buildOptions": {
        "define": [ "NET_STANDARD" ]
      }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "warningsAsErrors": true
  },

  "configurations": {
    "Release": {
      "buildOptions": {
        "xmlDoc": true,
        "optimize": true
      }
    },
    "Debug": {
      "buildOptions": {
        "xmlDoc": false,
        "optimize": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```